# Push notification only for Android

Tags: codenameone

I am developing mobile application using code name one and need to implement push notifications.I checked in code name one pricing for Professional users charging 79$ per month. 
Is it possible to give support push notification only for android with less price?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have no way to distinguish push types so that's not really an option.